# Javascript prototype inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

This is not the actual project i am working on but simple code to understand what am i doing wrong.

I have created a object named **NumSelector** and trying to use method **validator** which i have inherited using prototype. I get error **"validator is not defined"**

```
function NumSelector(num)
{
    if(validator(num))
      console.log("NUmber is positive");
    else
      console.log("Number s negative");
}

NumSelector.prototype.validator = function(num)
{
  if(num>0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
};
```

Comment: @elclanrs now its says "Object [object global] has no method 'validator'"

Comment: You're instantiating with `new` right?

Comment: I suggest you check out some tutorials, see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FInheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: I dont understand why its returning the complete code when i type x = new NumSelector(1)

Answer (score -1):

Use `this.validator()` in the if condition instead of `validator()`

```
function NumSelector(num)
{
    if(this.validator(num))
      console.log("NUmber is positive");
    else
      console.log("Number s negative");
}

NumSelector.prototype.validator = function(num)
{
  if(num>0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Right - it takes a keen eye to see that there's one single change between this block of code and the OP's block of code (the `this.validator` in the `if` check). This needs to be called out in the answer. That said: if adding `this` fixes the problem, it's a valid answer.

Comment: This was proposed above and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19330890/javascript-prototype-inheritance-not-working/19331290#comment28636278_19330890) was the answer.